# Receive form data in an array in node.js using Express?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want to create a form which makes a request of type POST and send the data to the  node.js server (using express).

How can the form sent and received as an array in the server?

Comment: Please put some code, html + server files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP introduced an extension to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data format that allows complex data structures to be encoded. Express has support for that format via the body-parser module.

Name the fields with `[]` at the end of the name.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>What animals do you like?</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="Cats"> Cats</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="Dogs"> Dogs</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="Tortoises"> Tortoises</label>
</fieldset>
```

Then, in express, use the [body-parser middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and turn on *extended* support.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

When you read the [request body](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body), `animals` will be an array (or unset if none of the checkboxes were checked).

Comment: Thanks man, it was helpful and I am a noobie in nodejs